# Angular4 Router: Event when routerLinkActive classes are added

Tags: angular, router

I have a short question I want to select the active route class, which is defined with Angular4 like this:

```
$(".navigation > nav.side > ul > li.active ul.sublist").show();
```

Currently, I call this method in the `onInit()` method of Angular, but this don't work. I figured out that the `routerLinkActive` classes are not added, when the `onInit()` method is fired. Now my question: Is there a event which fires when the router finished adding this classes? I need a event which is only **fired once on page reload**!

I have a little work-around but this is not really unreliable:

```
onInit(): void {
    setTimeout(() => {
        $(".navigation > nav.side > ul > li.active ul.sublist").show();
    }, 1);
}
```

Comment: Is this selecting an HTML element? Could you use a template reference variable instead? Or use ngClass in the template instead of trying to control it from the component?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're trying to use jQuery in your Angular app. Angular folk will recommend doing it the "Angular" way, which I'd suggest as well. If you want to apply some CSS if the current `routerLink` is `active` you can do something like

```
<a routerLink="/user/bob" routerLinkActive="active-link">Bob</a>
```

from https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/router/index/RouterLinkActive-directive.html

If you're trying to show that specific element you can use ngIf or [hidden] bound to the element you want to hide.

your view

```
<navigation>
  <nav class="side">
    <ul>
      <li class="active">
        <ul class="sublist" *ngIf="showSublist">
        <-- or
        <ul class="sublist" [hidden]="!showSublist">
```

!ngIf evaluates to display: none whereas hidden is visibility hidden

component would be

```
showSubList() {
    this.showSublist = true;
}
```

Comment: My problem is that I have multiply lists with a sublist inside  and I want to slide down the sublist if the list is active and slide up the sublist if the list is no longer active.

Comment: Can you create an example plunkr so I can see what you're going for